# SQLAlchemy: how to implement float division on update?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have such updating query:

```
DBSession.query(Model).filter(Model.id == id).update({
    Model.count:  Model.count + 1,
    Model.wins:   Model.wins + trigger,
    Model.rating: (Model.wins + trigger) / (Model.count + 1)
}, synchronize_session=False)
```

When I use this it always returns `Models.rating = 0`, because `wins < count`.  But I need to get float number, like `0.02389`.

How to get that? Maybe there is some division func in sqlalchemy (which I haven't found) or smth else...

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This question is old, but i didn't find an answer in other threads, what it worked for me was [casting](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.cast):

```
from sqlalchemy import cast, Float

cast(Model.wins, Float) / cast(Model.count, Float)
```

Answer (score -1):

I think all you need to do is force python to do a float division:

```
float(Model.wins + trigger) / float(Model.count + 1)
```

From your code it looks like this has nothing to do with sqlalchemy, but is just a plain old expression being evaluated while initializing the dictionary that gets passed to `update`.

This bites me all the time too...

Comment: There is an error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`

Comment: oh dear. right. now i'm squinting at it differently and see my post was totally wrong. grr. off to check sqlalchemy Model class...